# ArcEnterprise issue with connecting to Developer WAB?

Tags: arcgis, esri, wab

I have been having some issues connecting to the Developer WAB application from the Enterprise instance I am currently using. I have followed all of the steps outlined in the guide provided by Esri [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm) and seem to be running into an authentication loop in my browser.

There is an error in the web page Console that states that there is 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present on the requested resource'.

The error displaying in the Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS says that there is no token found, and so redirects back to the 'setportalurl' page. Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

```
No token is found, redirect /webappbuilder/ to /webappbuilder/?action=setportalurl
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As the Developer WAB uses the machine name and port for it's domain, ArcGIS is rejecting the request for security reasons.

If you paste the full domain into the "Allow Origins" section of your portal's security settings and save, this should then work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be applicable to your scenario, but for people getting the same error when working from localhost this can be an issue with WAB Dev Edition's self-signed cert.

The solution for me was to allow the chrome flag:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```